# I am looking for ideas about how to fix in place my under-cabinet duct

Tags: hvac

I am replacing my kitchen and I finally get to fix a problem that has annoyed me for as long as I have lived in this house - the HVAC duct in the kitchen just dumped air under the poorly installed cabinets, so cold or hot air leaked just blew into the cavity and then leaked out wherever it could.

So I have built a channel which I will fasten to the rough toe kick, and then cover with the finished toe kick. I have this thing in place, and it has about 1/2" movement in every direction, so when I put the cabinet down, I can put it into position and screw it to the toe kick.

I am trying to figure out how to seal it. What I have come up with is adhesive weather stripping between the two sides and the floor, and along the face where this duct hits the toe kick. If that works, I still need a way to hold it down. I was thinking I could put some foam on top of it, so when I place the cabinet, the cabinet will push the foam down, and press the duct to the floor, compressing the weather stripping and sealing everything. But will this foam lose it's tension after some years and let some space open where the duct hits the floor?

I also thought about screwing the thing to the floor, but then I lose the ability to make the small adjustments after the cabinet is down.

Any ideas about how to hold it down? I have access to the underside of the floor. But that sounds like a mess.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My thought is to put the cabinet in place where it will be permanently mounted (make sure it is EXACTLY where it will be when you drive the screws to attach it to the house).

Take a pencil and mark the floor where the opening already is in the toe kick as well as the rear face of the toe kick. Attach the duct to the floor 1/2 the thickness of the weather strip to the rear of the back face of the toe kick. Example: if you are going to use 1/2" weather strip, offset the duct by 1/4" to the rear of the toe kick rear face.

Caulk and seal the duct to the floor. Attach the weather strip to the front face of the duct. Carefully slide the cabinet to its final position (avoiding lateral movement once it makes contact with the weather strip). Attach the cabinet to the house.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of foam use a coil, or leaf, spring to hold it down.

Or you could squirt spray foam in above it after you get it in position.